# Return collection of eager loaded models in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a list of `Top Shows` on my webpage which are generated from grouping episodes by `show_id` and sorting them by `view`. I eager load the `Show` in the query like so:

```
public function getPopularShows($amount = null)
{
    if (!$amount) {
        return $this->episode->groupBy('show_id')->orderBy('views', 'desc')->with('show')->get();
    }
    return $this->episode->groupBy('show_id')->orderBy('views', 'desc')->with('show')->get()->take($amount);
}
```

However, this obviously returns a collection of `episodes` and I want a collection of `shows`. Is there a smart way of doing this?

The only way I can think of right now is doing an `array_map` and swap out the episode with the show.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you try to achieve, but maybe something like this is what you need

```
public function getPopularShows($amount = null)
{
    return Show::whereIn('id', function($q) use ($amount) {
         $q = $q->selectRaw('show_id')->from('episodes')->orderBy('views','DESC');
          if ($amount) {
            $q = $q->take($amount);
          }
          $q->get();
    })->get();
}
```